# Figure out clients that have the wrong mail server

Tags: linux, email, hosting, migration, exim

My company is currently in the process of migrating our mail servers from one machine to another. Now most of the clients are currently using the following POP server :

mail.username.zyx

Wich will be fowarded, so no problems here.
My problem is some clients have the following servers configured :

oldserver.perseidestech.net

perseidestech.net

domainname.zyx

All the clients who have the preceding configuration will have to re-configure their outlook clients to continue using the mail services. My question is: how can i know what clients have the wrong server setup without interacting with them? Is there any log file that tells me what server they have configured? Thanks a lot

EDIT : im running CentOS with WHM / cPanel

Comment: DNS Server query log would show that information

Comment: Where does one find that specifig log?

Comment: It would depend on what kind of DNS Server you're running and *if* you have the log enabled.

Comment: Running BIND under WHM, not sure how to check if logging is enabled

Comment: Your onsite DNS server is configured through WHM?

Comment: If u understand the question well, yes. Our server Mars is hosting a little over 150 DNS Zones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into `oldserver` and run tcpdump/wireshark.  Any client connecting to `oldserver` over mail ports (25/tcp smtp, 110/tcp pop3, 143/tcp imap, 465/tcp smtp ssl, 995/tcp pop3 ssl, 993/tcp imap ssl) needs to be reconfigured.

The other thing you could do to force everyone over to to make a DNS CNAME record from `oldserver` point to `newserver`.

Comment: Hmm, i just found out about rndc querylog, this prolly will do it for what we need. Concerning wireshark, i thought it only worked for PC? Is it easy to use in a command-line environement with CentOS? Also concerning the CNAME possibility, the thing is, some clients use the domain name of our web servers as their mail servers, so adding a CNAME would effectively make them unable to reach over 150 websites

Comment: If you have root on the oldserver, tcpdump will work from the command line.  The DNS log is a good place to start but won't catch all cases.

Comment: Alright i will produce a little execution plan and present it to my local sysadmin, thanks a lot!

Comment: I should add that NAT on client networks may mean you don't have the "actual" client IPs.  You'd need to run a similar tcpdump/wireshark on the client network router *pre*-NAT to get any private IPs for clients.  Still, running at the server and getting *zero* mail traffic is a prereq for shutting it down.

Comment: Well lots of clients will need to be contacted nevertheless, but at least using the tcpdump command i can make sure ALL clients have their mail pointing to the new server, should be helpful in the process